# Query Not Giving results when date condition is added to where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

The query Below Return Correct Results if the where clause for Between Two dates is not added otherwise it return zero  , this is the sql equivalent of the hibernate query that i have created.
in my Database Date is Saved as for ex:- 12-Feb-2014 
Can anyone pls give me a solution how to fetch results between two given dates.

```
select distinct count(customerjob0_.JOB_NUMBER) as col_0_0_ from JOB_CUSTOMER customerjob0_
left outer join SERVICE_LOCATION serviceloc1_ on customerjob0_.SERVICE_LOCATION_CODE=serviceloc1_.SERVICE_LOCATION_CODE 
left outer join JOB_CONTRACTS jobcontrac2_ on customerjob0_.JOB_NUMBER=jobcontrac2_.JOB_NUMBER 
left outer joinS CONTACTS contact3_ on jobcontrac2_.CONTACT_ID=contact3_.CONTACT_ID 
left outer join CUSTOMERS customer4_ on jobcontrac2_.CUST_CODE=customer4_.CUST_CODE 
left outer join CONTRACTS contract5_ on jobcontrac2_.CONTRACT_CODE=contract5_.CONTRACT_CODE 
left outer join JOB_CONTRACT_INVOICE jobcontrac6_ on jobcontrac2_.JOB_CONTRACT_ID=jobcontrac6_.JOB_CONTRACT_ID 
where to_char(customerjob0_.BU_NAME)='xYX01'
and (to_char(customerjob0_.BRANCH_NAME) like 'UX902')
and (to_char(customerjob0_.JOB_STATUS) in (2390 , 23400))
and to_char(customerjob0_.JOB_TYPE)='TEST' 
and (to_char(customerjob0_.JOB_FINISH_DATE) between '18-Sep-2008' and '18-Sep-2015');
```

Comment: You are comparing the _STRING_ "12-Feb-2014" to the _STRING_ "18-Sep-20[08|15]". And because Feb != Sep it will never work. try comparing it as Time-Values?

Comment: Actually that is only for example that i have written 12-Feb-2014 actually there are many dates in the database

Comment: Does not change the Problem - "Feb" will never be between "Sep" and "Sep", because they are strings.

Comment: EGOrecords can you pls try  elaborate i am not good at databases

Comment: You are comparing strings to each other, that has nothing to do with databases. you are casting ("to_char") your date into a string and compare it to another string. If you omit the casting, it might work.

Comment: EGOrecords i did exactly that and it worked anyways thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct count(customerjob0_.JOB_NUMBER) as col_0_0_ from JOB_CUSTOMER customerjob0_
left outer join SERVICE_LOCATION serviceloc1_ on customerjob0_.SERVICE_LOCATION_CODE=serviceloc1_.SERVICE_LOCATION_CODE 
left outer join JOB_CONTRACTS jobcontrac2_ on customerjob0_.JOB_NUMBER=jobcontrac2_.JOB_NUMBER 
left outer joinS CONTACTS contact3_ on jobcontrac2_.CONTACT_ID=contact3_.CONTACT_ID 
left outer join CUSTOMERS customer4_ on jobcontrac2_.CUST_CODE=customer4_.CUST_CODE 
left outer join CONTRACTS contract5_ on jobcontrac2_.CONTRACT_CODE=contract5_.CONTRACT_CODE 
left outer join JOB_CONTRACT_INVOICE jobcontrac6_ on jobcontrac2_.JOB_CONTRACT_ID=jobcontrac6_.JOB_CONTRACT_ID 
where to_char(customerjob0_.BU_NAME)='xYX01'
and (to_char(customerjob0_.BRANCH_NAME) like 'UX902')
and (to_char(customerjob0_.JOB_STATUS) in (2390 , 23400))
and to_char(customerjob0_.JOB_TYPE)='TEST' 
and customerjob0_.JOB_FINISH_DATE between '18-Sep-2008' and '18-Sep-2015';
```

Actually i removed to_char from the where clause for date and it worked